# How to Inverse a Map with Duplicate Keys/Values

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap, maps

I have a map with duplicate values and different keys. I want to reverse a map but want to retain the values associated to keys. It'll be more clear from below:

Original Map -

```
{key1=value1, key2=value1, key3=value2}
```

Expected Output -

```
{value1=key1, value1=Key2, value2=key3}
```

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1","value1");
    map.put("key2","value1");
    map.put("key3","value2");

    System.out.println(map);
    
    Map<String, String> inverseMap = MapUtils.invertMap(map); 
    System.out.println(inverseMap);
```

I am getting only `{value1=key2, value2=key3}` as duplicate keys are not allowed in maps. So is there any way get the expected output.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You know you can't have duplicated keys, but you want duplicated keys: that's hard. What you can have is `{value1: [key1, key2], value2: [key3]}`

Comment: Or you can use a multimap structure, like [Guava](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) offers.

Comment: What you want is a tuple, not a map entry. Java doesn't have such a class, but you could go 3rd party or make your own

Answer (score 1):

Picking up on @shmosel's idea of using Guava:

```java
Multimap<String, String> inverseMap = ImmutableListMultimap.copyOf(map.entrySet()).inverse();
System.out.println(inverseMap);
System.out.println(inverseMap.entries());
```

This prints:

```
{value1=[key1, key2], value2=[key3]}
[value1=key1, value1=key2, value2=key3]
```

A [Multimap](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/latest/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is

> A collection that maps keys to values, similar to Map, but in which each key may be associated with multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

you can't.,
keys cant be duplicates

1st you are assigning value1=key1

2n time when u assign value1= key2

"key1" is replaced by "key2"